# How to get the output from a Mac OS executable file in node js?

Tags: node.js

I have an executable file that outputs every few seconds of data once i run it via the Terminal on Mac OS.
How can i get the data using node js?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the command, which you run in the terminal, as a Node.js child process using `spawn` or `exec`.

Example:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

ls.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

The more information you can find [here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a way to execute the file by path? I mean to run the file and get the stream of the data it outputs?

Comment: Do you mean a .sh file?